# ngModel não muda o Toggle do Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic, ionic2, typescript, localstorage

Tenho um toggle que habilita e desabilita uma função, isso já funciona, o que nao funciona é o estado do Toggle na View, o toggle sempre fica ativado mesmo com a ngmodel=false. código abaixo:

**View:**

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="Ativar" (ionChange)="SimNao()"></ion-toggle>
```

**TS:**

```
SimNao(){
    if(this.Ativar == true){
      this.storage.set('ativar', true);
    }
    if(this.Ativar == false){
      this.storage.set('ativar', false);
    }
  }
```

**Console**

```
console.log(this.Ativar);
```

Tanto no console, quanto no local storage os valores são alternados entre True e False e no Local Storage tudo está funcionando, a função atualiza os dados normalmente. O unico problema é o toggle sempre estar ativado mesmo que o estado seja false.

Comment: `Activar` é um `get Activar()` ?

Comment: Eu não estava pegando em nenhum momento o valor do this.Ativar no local storage, por isso o erro persistiu. Mas consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver pegando o valor do toggle que estava armazenado no *LocalStorage*, nesse código eu não pego o valor do Toggle, então a solução foi criar dentro do construtor o código abaixo.

```
this.storage.get('ativar').then((data) => {
    this.Ativar = data;
});
```

Dessa forma eu passo o estado correto da condição armazenada no Banco.